# Schedule live stream

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am part of a church that has started using YouTUbe over the pandemic to live stream service.

We intend on continuing this ad infinitum, however the tedium of having to schedule a live stream manually isn't ideal.

Is there a way to call an API to automatically schedule a livestream, and return the streams URL (to save into the database)?

Comment: Hi brother in Lord, our church is also trying to build that as well. Thanks for asking, God bless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: yes, there is a set of API endpoints that allows you to achieve your goals.

Go read the official [YouTube Live Streaming API Overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started), then follow its instructions.

The official reference would be of very much use during your program development: [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/).

You did not mentioned the level of your acquaintance with the YouTube Data API, therefore, I'll also mention an important doc you have to absorb too:
[Implementing OAuth 2.0 Authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication). Depending of the type of application you'll choose to develop (desktop app, server-side/client-side JavaScript, etc.), you need to absorb further one of the docs referenced therein.

Comment: brilliant, i will have a gander. The aim will be to schedule the stream from server side within the wordpress instance when a user create a "sermon" object. OAuth wont be too much of an issue to implement, my day job is running an OAuth service for a company :)

Comment: excellent @stvar now just to work out which APIs to use ...

Comment: @DrogoNevets: please post new questions when encountering road blocks.